# MVVM + UserControl + UserControl + DependencyProperty

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have a user control which displays addresses housed inside of another page that is bound to a viewmodel. The viewmodel has a primitive *User* which has a collection of *Address* objects. The User control will reside on several pages so I would like to be able to bind it to the address list via a dependency property. While my current solution is working, something about it just doesn't feel right and I thought I'd ask for a second opinion. I have chopped out a lot of code for brevity's sake.

Basically the page binds to the dependency property in the usercontrols code behind which then updates the usercontrol's datagrid by setting it's itemsource. This seems to me to break the basic tenants of MVVM.

AddressListView control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Insight.Controls.AddressListView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
    xmlns:tk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
    xmlns:command="clr-namespace:PrismFramework.Implementors.Commanding;assembly=PrismFramework"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="840">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <command:ObservableCommand x:Name="EditAddressCommand" Value="{Binding EditAddressCmd}"/>
        <command:ObservableCommand x:Name="DeleteAddressCommand" Value="{Binding DeleteAddressCmd}"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <sdk:DataGrid Name="dgAddresses" 
                    Height="Auto" 
                    Width="Auto" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    HeadersVisibility="None" >
            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="dgcAddresses" 
                            Width="*" >
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border x:Name="bdrAddress" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    Height="Auto"
                                    Width="Auto"
                                    BorderBrush="Silver"  
                                    BorderThickness="1" 
                                    Padding="0" 
                                    Margin="1,1,1,1">
                                <Grid x:Name="grdAddressItem"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                        Height="Auto" 
                                        Width="Auto">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="17" MinHeight="17"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="17" MinHeight="17"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="17" MinHeight="17"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="17" MinHeight="17"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="17" MinHeight="17"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="17" MinHeight="17"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="17" MinHeight="17"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="55" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Padding="0,0,5,0" Text="Type:" TextAlignment="Right" />
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Padding="0" Text="{Binding Path=AType}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row ="1" Grid.Column="0" Padding="0,0,5,0" Text="Address 1:" TextAlignment="Right" />
<!-- List Of Similar Fields ->
                                    <Grid x:Name="grdAddressEditOptions" 
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                            Height="Auto"
                                            Width="Auto"
                                            Grid.Column="3"
                                            Grid.RowSpan="7" >
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Button x:Name="btnEdit"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                Height="Auto"
                                                Width="Auto"
                                                Grid.Row="0"
                                                Padding="4,5,4,8"
                                                Margin="0,8,10,0"
                                                Command="{Binding Value, Source={StaticResource EditAddressCommand}}"
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding}" >
                                            <Button.Content>
                                                <Image x:Name="btnEditIcon"
                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                        Height="Auto"
                                                        Width="Auto"
                                                        Source="/Insight.ModuleUser;component/Images/edit.png" 
                                                        Visibility="Visible" />
                                            </Button.Content>
                                        </Button>
                                        <Button x:Name="btnDelete"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                Height="Auto"
                                                Width="Auto"
                                                Grid.Row="2"
                                                Padding="4,5,4,8"
                                                    Margin="0,0,10,5"
                                                Command="{Binding Value, Source={StaticResource  DeleteAddressCommand}}"
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding}" >
                                            <Button.Content>
                                                <Image x:Name="btnDeleteIcon"
                                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                            Height="Auto"
                                                            Width="Auto"
                                                            Source="/Insight.ModuleUser;component/Images/delete.png" 
                                                            Visibility="Visible" />
                                            </Button.Content>
                                        </Button>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        </sdk:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

AddressListView code behind:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports Insight.DataServices.Primitives

Partial Public Class AddressListView
Inherits UserControl

Public ReadOnly AddressesProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Addresses", GetType(ObservableCollection(Of Address)), GetType(AddressListView), New PropertyMetadata(Nothing, New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf OnAddressesChanged)))

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
End Sub

Public Property Addresses As ObservableCollection(Of Address)
    Get
        Return DirectCast(GetValue(AddressesProperty), ObservableCollection(Of Address))
    End Get
    Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of Address))
        SetValue(AddressesProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub OnAddressesChanged()
    Me.dgAddresses.ItemsSource = Addresses
End Sub

End Class
```

Base page:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Insight.ModuleUser.Views.EditUserView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"    
    xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity.InteractionRequest;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"  
    xmlns:cm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=System.Windows"
    xmlns:data="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Data;assembly=System.Windows"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Insight.ModuleUser.ViewModels"
    xmlns:command="clr-namespace:PrismFramework.Implementors.Commanding;assembly=PrismFramework"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Insight.Controls;assembly=Insight.Controls"
    xmlns:modalDialogs="clr-namespace:Insight.Controls.ModalDialogViews;assembly=Insight.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="1144" 
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignData /Insight.ModuleUser;component/SampleData/EditUserViewModelSampleData.xaml}">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <command:ObservableCommand x:Name="OpenProjectCommand" Value="{Binding OpenProjectCmd}"/>
        <command:ObservableCommand x:Name="OpenPaymentCommand" Value="{Binding OpenPaymentCmd}"/>
        <command:ObservableCommand x:Name="OpenInvoiceCommand" Value="{Binding OpenInvoiceCmd}"/>
        <command:ObservableCommand x:Name="OpenPaymentItemCommand" Value="{Binding OpenPaymentItemCmd}"/>

        <command:ObservableCommand x:Name="EditPhoneCommand" Value="{Binding EditPhoneNumberCmd}"/>
        <command:ObservableCommand x:Name="DeletePhoneCommand" Value="{Binding DeletePhoneNumberCmd}"/>
        <command:ObservableCommand x:Name="EditEmailAddressCommand" Value="{Binding EditEmailAddressCmd}"/>
        <command:ObservableCommand x:Name="DeleteEmailAddressCommand" Value="{Binding DeleteEmailAddressCmd}"/>

    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >


                <controls:AddressListView x:Name="ctrlAddressListView" 
                    Addresses="{Binding User.Addresses}" />

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a perfectly reasonable approach. However, you could use binding in your user control view, rather than setting the items source in code.

To do this you need to set the `DataContext` of the user control to be your user control type. This could be done either in the code behind for the user control (setting `this.DataContext = this`), or through element binding in XAML:

```
<UserControl
...
 x:Name="MyName"
 DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MyName}"
```

However, my approach would be not to use a user control at all, as all you're really talking about is view composition and reusing a particular section of the view between other views.

View composition is extremely straightforward with an MVVM framework such as [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/). In this case you would have an `AddressViewModel` and `AddressView`, and use a `ContentControl` to inject the `AddressView` into the base view:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="AddressViewModel" />
```

Comment: I agree this one is very simplistic. It is my proof of concept for several others that I have that are much more complex with multiple nested controls, etc. I am not familiar with DependencyProperties so I wanted to make sure I was using best practices approach rather than shooting from the hip and then discovering later that I was shooting myself in the foot. :)